# Excel Multiple functions in one cell

Tags: excel, function

I want to get the greater of two numbers : `=MAX(A1,A2)`
Add a number: `=MAX(A1,A2)+A3`
and then multiply it buy a number A4 (this is where I'm stuck)
The `MAX`and `+` have to come before the `*` this is where it gets frustrating.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: off topic is the stupidest thing i've heard. Thanks to those who answered. It isn't "why isn't this working" It's how do you___ . And I said what I wanted to do, and 2 ppl got it 5 where to retarded, they may even find reading my question and it's answers useful.

Comment: this is off-topic for this site.  This type of question is better suited for `SuperUser.com`.  This site is for programming-related questions and excel formulas do not fit into that subject.

Comment: @Mr.Mascaro Then why do we have a tag for `excel-formula`

Comment: @Bijan, because some programming problems might involve formulas too, but simple questions like this are not programming related as spelled out in the help guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

Use parenthesis

```
=(MAX(A1,A2)+A3)*A4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
=((MAX(A1,A2))+A3)*A4
```

Use a lot of brakcets. Hope this helps

Comment: Worked as well, Thanks